# Sort Table Data on table Header Click

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, json, sorting

I have my table header which is inside a ng-repeat like as follows

```
<th class="sortable" ng-repeat="label in selection">{{label}} &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
```

As you can see I have a class sortable in the table header already but its not working

and the in the controller my sortable function is

```
$(".sortable").click(function(){
        var o = $(this).hasClass('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        $('.sortable').removeClass('asc').removeClass('desc');
        $(this).addClass(o);

        var colIndex = $(this).prevAll().length;
        var tbod = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody");
        var rows = tbod.find("tr");

        rows.sort(function(a,b){
            var A = $(a).find("td").eq(colIndex).text();
            var B = $(b).find("td").eq(colIndex).text();

            if (!isNaN(A)) A = Number(A);
            if (!isNaN(B)) B = Number(B);

            return o == 'asc' ? A > B : B > A;
        });

            $.each(rows, function(index, ele){
                tbod.append(ele);
            });
        });
```

Its not working. Can someone please help me? it is highly appreciated.

Comment: fiddle/plnkr possible?

Comment: @tanmay, I resolved this already, gonna edit my question and ask a different one Thanks!

Comment: can you not use something like [sortElements](https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/tree/master/sortElements) or [tablesorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter) or even better, why introduce jQuery when you can achieve it using Angular itself?